# Angular provider not setting value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-provider

I've made my own module, with a provider. I want other users to be able to override the default config:

```
angular.module('mymodule').provider('mymoduleConfig', [function() {

    var object = {
        theme: 'default'
    };

    var updated = {};

    this.setConfig = function(override) {
        console.log('Config updated...', override);
        updated = override;
    }

    return {
        $get: function() {
            return {
                config: angular.extend(object, updated)
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Within my own app, I include the `mymodule` and try to use the `setConfig`, however it doesn't trigger. When I call `

```
angular.module('example', ['mymodule'])

angular.module('example').config(['mymoduleConfigProvider', function(mymoduleConfigProvider) {
    mymoduleConfigProvider.setConfig({
        theme: 'bootstrap'
    });
}]);
```

The `setConfig` never gets called, but I cannot figure out why!

Answer (score 0):

`setConfig` method should be kept outside the rerurn object and it should be added inside `this` context of function.

Then it could be accessible from the config phase

**Update**

The reason behind it was not working is you are explicitly returning an object from your provider which is flushing the `this.setConfig` method like you were also included `$get` function in that object that's why it is accessible in your current implementation. I'd suggest you should not return object from provider you should create a `this.$get` function and then assign then return object from it.

**Provider**

```
angular.module('mymodule', []).provider('mymoduleConfig', [function() {

  var object = {
    theme: 'default'
  };

  var updated = {};

  this.setConfig = function(override) {
    console.log('Config updated...', override);
    updated = override;
  }

  this.$get = function() {
    //returning object from `.$get` function
    return {
      config: angular.extend(object, updated)
    }
  }
}]);
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/gZNB4pymvYGjKJoXkhmP?p=preview)

Comment: @Alias does this helped you..?